# Inject some properties to class before function fromJson

Tags: java, fromjson

I want inject property to class before induce fromJson.

```
PrimitiveDocument document = null;
document = (PrimitiveDocument) gson.fromJson(requestBody.toString(), AcceptPathDocument.class);
```

In AcceptPathDocument induce constructor PrimitiveDocument:

```
if (!this.getApplicationTag().equals("")) {
    Database db = Master.getDB(this.getApplicationTag());
    try {
        this.doc = db.createDocument();
        this.setForm(this.getForm());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I have applicationTag in requestBody so when this code is running applicationTag is empty. How I can inject application tag from requestbody before induce fromJson?

Comment: Why don't you set the form after the deserialization ?

Answer (score 1):

May decomposing  **AcceptPathDocument**  class to two class helps.
this means that first convert *json* to *pojo* then add this object as a field to second class. like decorator pattern.